# Selenium RC selenium-testrunner.js Access denied error on IEProxy - Help?

Tags: internet-explorer, selenium-rc, permissions

```
Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)
Timestamp: Wed, 28 Apr 2010 02:07:17 UTC


Message: Access is denied.

Line: 177
Char: 9
Code: 0
URI: http://www.google.com/selenium-server/core/scripts/selenium-testrunner.js
```

Hi guys,
i'm just starting to learn up on selenium and while testing using mostly test cases and test suite creating using selenium IDE firefox, i'm having some problem getting it to work properly in internet explorer.

this is the cmd line that i'm using:

```
java -jar "selenium-server.jar" -htmlSuite *iexploreproxy "http://www.google.com/" tests/OR_Discount_UAT_Suite.htm results.html -userExtensions user-extensions.js
```

i try using the *iexplore but kept getting session id expired error and try with the proxy version instead.

i can now see the testrunner but keep getting the access denied error.
i then try the same cmd line using firefox:

```
java -jar "selenium-server.jar" -htmlSuite *firefox3 "http://www.google.com/" tests/OR_Discount_UAT_Suite.htm results.html -userExtensions user-extensions.js
```

FYI, i've already unchecked the auto detect proxy setting in IE8.

and i can get everything running perfectly. so im not sure what's the problem right now :(
anybody can help?

thanks!

### Updates:

I'm seeing this proxy under LAN setting, i think it's set by selenium:
file:///C:/DOCUME~1/Melaos_~1/LOCALS~1/Temp/customProfileDir985530/proxy.pac

and the content is:

```
function FindProxyForURL(url, host) {
        return 'PROXY localhost:4444; DIRECT';
}
```

Comment: It's just too bad that the selenium server port is not embedded in the URL. As it is, a separate pac script like the one above is needed for each remote browser...

Answer (score 1):

Did you consider changing your local Intranet Zone permissions for JavaScript? I bet that it is being blocked upon startup. You could test by  creating a HTML file with an included javascript/hello world function. If it executes upon doubleclick, then you have an issue somewhere else. Usually, IE will popup an info bar asking to give permissions to execute scripts

Answer (score 0):

I would double check firewall setting, ie8 security settings(especially so there are not to high restrictions on javascripts) and that the host files does not have values messing up localhost-pointer.